# Using values returned by Meteor template helpers for other calculations [SOLVING WITH AGGREGATION]

Tags: arrays, meteor, meteor-blaze

I'm having trouble understanding how to run some simple calculations in a Meteor app.

The following helpers return three values (numerator, denominator and the result of dividing the two).  The first two values currently come from a collection (will eventually come from an API feed) and are dependent on two values from a different collection (called using Template.parentData).  The third value is not saved to the database.  This sequence is repeated through a loop to display  the three values in a table.

```
Template.ValuationTable.helpers({
    selections: function () {
        var selected = this.valuationSelections;
        return Companies.find({ticker: {$in: selected}})
    },
    valuationNum: function() {
        var valuationMetric = Template.parentData(1).valuationMetric;
        switch (valuationMetric) {
            case "EV/Revenue":
                return this.enterpriseValue.toFixed(1);
                break;
            case "EV/EBITDA":
                return this.enterpriseValue.toFixed(1);
                break;
            default:
                return "";
        }
    },
    valuationDen: function() {
        var valuationMetric = Template.parentData(1).valuationMetric;
        var valuationPeriod = Template.parentData(1).valuationPeriod;
        switch (valuationMetric) {
            case "EV/Revenue":
                switch (valuationPeriod) {
                    case "LTM":
                        return this.ltm.revenue.toFixed(1);
                        break;
                    case "FY1":
                        return this.fy1.revenue.toFixed(1);
                        break;
                    case "FY2":
                        return this.fy2.revenue.toFixed(1);
                        break;
                }
                break;
            case "EV/EBITDA":
                switch (valuationPeriod) {
                    case "LTM":
                        return this.ltm.ebitda.toFixed(1);
                        break;
                    case "FY1":
                        return this.fy1.ebitda.toFixed(1);
                        break;
                    case "FY2":
                        return this.fy2.ebitda.toFixed(1);
                        break;
                }
                break;
            default:
                return "";
        }
    }
});

Template.registerHelper('divide', function(a, b) {
    return (a / b).toFixed(1);
    });

<template name="ValuationTable">
    {{#each selections}}
        <tr>
            <td>
                <a>${{valuationNum}}</a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a>${{valuationDen}}</a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a>{{divide valuationNum valuationDen}}x</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    {{/each}}
</template>
```

I need to then calculate the average and median of the series of third values, both to display on the page and to use as a data point for D3.  I know I need these values in an array to calculate average and median, but I don't know how to "get" them from the helper results.

First off, should I instead be building the switch in an object (in the subscription perhaps?) and passing that into the helper?  If so, any guidance would be appreciated.

Second, how do I get the third value to add to an array?  Can I access it directly from the helper?

Thanks in advance, sorry if these are two different questions, I think they are closely related though.

EDIT:

I realized, per Michel's suggestion of `meteorhacks:aggregate`, that I was thinking about this incorrectly and that aggregation is needed, not helpers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's impractical to perform aggregation operations in helper functions that deal with individual documents. You may find a package such as [meteorhacks:aggregate](https://atmospherejs.com/meteorhacks/aggregate) to implement aggregation functions.

Why is it impractical? For starters, due to reactivity any value and even the number of documents can change at any moment. You can't really perform aggregation *as the documents are displayed* in functions that have a scope of one document.

Comment: Thanks - so are you saying I need to use aggregation functions for any mathematical calculation?  Some of these are just division and multiplication, I wouldn't think it was necessary (I also don't know how to use them). I am brand new to development, so I'm not even sure if my questions here are specific to Meteor or to Javascript.

Comment: Aggregation is useful when executing functions over multiple documents. Your simple division (numerator/denominator) takes two numbers and, if both are from the same document, can be performed in a helper (one document at a time - the value of *this*). Your average and median require all the documents, therefore aggregation. Your question is more Meteor than javascript because it involves blaze templates and helper functions.

Comment: Thanks very much - will need to spend some time learning this, hope you don't mind if I wait till it works before accepting the answer!

Comment: Sure thing. The good thing about learning Meteor is that it rewards you quickly.

Comment: Michel, this is getting me toward the right answer.  I'm having a couple problems with the aggregation, but am posting separately to as to not muddy the original question.  Thanks.

Comment: Michel, I posted this question on aggregations as a follow-up, in case you have any guidance.  Thank you. http://stackoverflow.com/q/32708131/4168250